# Problems with BufferedReader / PrintWriter?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I'm using BufferedReader and PrintWriter to go through each line of an input file, make a change to some lines, and output the result. If a line doesn't undergo a change, it's just printed as is to the output file. For some reason however, the process ends prematurely. The code looks something like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(out);
String line = in.readLine();

while(line!=null)
{
   if(line is special)
      do edits and p.println(edited_line);
   else
      p.println(line);

   line = in.readLine();
}
```

However, for some odd reason, this process ends prematurely (actually prints out a half of a line) towards the very end of my input file. Any obvious reason for this? The while loop is clearly being ended by a null. And it's towards the end of my 250k+ line txt file. Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that no exceptions are being thrown? What would you do if an exception *was* thrown? Would it be logged?

Comment: Jon - don't forget that PrintWriter squeltches exceptions - you have to use the "checkError" method to see if one occurred.

Comment: Yes, but BufferedReader and FileReader don't - so the call to readLine() could have thrown.

Comment: What I'm saying is - since checkError isn't invoked, if PrintWriter threw an exception, it wouldn't be realized by this code.  This is a common problem when using PrintWriter...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where do you flush/close your PrintWriter or FileOutputStream ? If the program exits and this is not done, not all your results will be written out.

You need `out.close()`  (possibly a `p.flush()` as well?) at the end of your process to close the file output stream

Comment: Closing is better than simply flushing. +1

Comment: Don't forget to do this in a finally block in case there's an exception.

Comment: That should be p.close(). p.flush() *should* not be necessary but it's good to know that the PrintWriter does not flush before it closes the underlying stream. If that stream has a bug (-> doesn't flush on close, either), you'll have the same problem again.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a p.flush() after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

PrintWriter does not have autoflushing enabled, so its likely that the last bit of the file is not flushed before the program terminates.

Adding a 
`p.flush()` after your while loop should do the trick.